# Integrating a piecewise defined function in maxima

Tags: maxima

Say that I have the following function:

```
f(x) := if x<=0 then 0 else if x<=1 then 1 else -1;
```

Or any other piecewise defined function.

The function definition seems to work:

```
(%i9) f(-11);
f(1/2);
f(2);
(%o7) 0
(%o8) 1
(%o9) -1
```

However integration doesn't evaluate here. It is somehow possible to get the value of the integral here in Maxima? And if not, could it be done numerically in maxima?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`load(abs_integrate)` to get the abs_integrate package, which enables `integrate` to handle `unit_step`. You'll have to write your piecewise function in terms of `unit_step`. E.g.:

```
(%i1) load (abs_integrate) $
(%i2) e : unit_step(t) - 2*unit_step(t - 1) $
(%i3) integrate (e, t, a, b);
             abs(b) - b - 2 abs(b - 1) - abs(a) + a + 2 abs(a - 1)
(%o3)        -----------------------------------------------------
                                       2
```

For numerical integration, `quad_qags` (and other quadpack functions) can handle both `unit_step` and `if` expressions. `quad_qags` doesn't need `abs_integrate`.